# Google Sheets: "getrange is not a function"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Sorry, I am a beginner in script development. Just tried to access the background color of a cell (returned as color string) and being stuck with the error message "TypeError: getrange is not a function" in line 4.

```
function GetCellColor(input) 
{ 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
var cell = ss.getrange(input); 
var result = cell.getBackground(); 
return result 
}
```

I want to use it in a spreadsheet with reference to any other cell like

```
=GetCellColor(D24)
```

Comment: Methods are case sensitive. `getRange()` not `getrange()`. Also `getRange()` accepts a `string`So use : `=GetCellColor("D24")`

Comment: Thanks, works. Can I somehow change the script to work with =GetCellColor(A1) instead =GetCellColor("A1")? I would like to be able to use copy-paste with Google sheets automatically changing the cell reference accordingly (i.e. in conditional formatting).

Comment: Possible. There's a roundabount way: get the active cell, get the formula in the active cell as a string, use regex to parse out the string A1 in the formula. There are some  similar scripts here- search long and you may find some.  Alternatively, DIY by referencing official documentations like MDN.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can use a custom formula in custom formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the method [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) which takes a string as a parameter. So to answer the question from your comment you can't. But you could build the R1C1 notation string using other methods and concatenation which you could the use for copying and pasting.

### Example:

`=GetCellColor("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN())`